# At what point does an answer become an advert?

Tags: discussion, answers

I came across an (unaccepted) answer which was made up of a single line of text saying that "X lib does what you want", then a 630x630 image with the name of the lib linking to the lib on github.

The image doesn't add anything extra, it contains no useful information. It simply takes up space and provides more area to get a click.

I've not come across such an answer before so I'm looking for guidance on if they should be reported or if they're okay.

EDIT: I've flagged it as "Not an answer" as it simply links to a library, and doesn't explain how it can be used to solve the question.

EDIT 2: The flag was accepted as helpful, although as per the comments below it probably wasn't the right flag to use. If I were to do this again I'd likely flag it as "spam" instead, as it was obnoxious and added nothing of technical value.

Comment: No need to go beyond calling it a "link only answer" IMO. The canonical "your answer is in another castle" explanation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: @Gimby Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Gimby You must not have read Shog's answer very carefully, because "X lib does what you want" should *not* be flagged as NAA, link or no link.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot actually I did re-read it, actually thought to myself "err.. wait a minute, that makes this an invalid NAA target", but at that point the flag was already made :/ But you're absolutely right, me and the NAA flag don't get along at all. Not that I advised to flag it as such in this case, mind you.

Comment: I don't think the NAA flag has any value anywhere. I say this because I've seen arguments that NAA was used incorrectly nearly to the point of saying anything posted is an answer, even when it's not a correct answer or even when the question it answers is not the question that was asked. I don't agree with those arguments (well, an incorrect answer that at least attempts to answer what was asked is not NAA), but there you have it. As an example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888197/c-sharp-straight-up-answer-for-using-regex-to-compare-strings/32888280#32888280 my NAA was declined.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If the question asked how to do something, and the answer is "X lib does that" but doesn't say *how*, I'd say it's a link-only answer and could be flagged not-an-answer.  I like to leave a comment saying something like "If you're going to recommend a library, you should explain how to use it to do *foo*" to give the user some idea why their answer is getting deleted by review.  If the question directly asked for a library, the answer may be as good as the question deserves -- but that's a textbook example of why we close recommendation questions.

If the image is literally an advertisement, I'd check the user's other answers and either edit the image out with a comment (if this is the only one), or flag for mod attention (repeated), regarding the self-promotion policies.  I wouldn't be confident enough to flag as spam if it wasn't blatantly commercial.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be commercial at all, it's just rather obnoxious in the way it fills the page. Thanks for the PoV.

Comment: @AndyJ It doesn't have to be commercial to be an advertisement or spam.

Comment: Why do people always use foo/bar, it makes every example so much more complicated (not here of course, I'm just wondering)

Comment: @alex They're just placeholders. The idea is that you focus on the logic of the example, not the specific names. Further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868904/what-is-the-origin-of-foo-and-bar, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/69788/what-is-the-history-of-the-use-of-foo-and-bar-in-source-code-examples (What a weird, unrelated question to ask, though!)

Comment: @CodyGray I know, but it makes an example always more complicated than using real life representations imo. Sorry for going offtopic

Comment: I would say that "Use library X" is a bad answer, but it is an answer. It is not link only, since it contains the seed to the solution. So I would downvote but not flag.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck because using real product examples would invite distractions in the form of inevitable holy wars between EX: Vim vs Emacs vs Visual Studio vs Eclipse vs XCode vs "a simple editor" vs etc. vs etc. vs etc. (editors are merely representative, list is not intended to be complete); that would be triggered when clueless fanboi's are unable to tell the difference between a random item as an example and either dissing the One True Way To Do It (wTfM) or endorsing one of the many Absolutely Unthinkably Wrong Ways To Do It (wTfM).  Using a generic placeholder largely avoids this.

Comment: @Anders After seeing the extended discussion about this I think I wouldn't flag it as NAA any more. I would flag it as spam though. It was simply a large logo with zero technical information, so at best it added nothing of technical value, and at worst it was an advert that wasted lots of space.

Comment: @Anders As [Adam Katz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519360/adam-katz) put it in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984017/#comment58869727_35591724): "Please provide a more detailed description, such as what minicap is, why it helps, and how to use it. Stack Overflow answers should contain the requested guidance without requiring readers to follow links."  I understand not wanting to lose something that still might help a future reader, though.

Comment: @Anders Mods generally decline such flags, but reviewers will recommend deletion.  I don't know what to do about this disconnect between policy and practice.  I guess ideally we'd put link-only answers through an H&I-like queue to see if the relevant information can be summarized in the answer.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom No matter what, I think leaving a comment like the one you quoted is always a good thing.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck  if it's a real life example then you might make assumptions as to how it works, that may help you or it may hurt you.  You  will  have a far more proper understanding if you can understand a foo/bar / blob / asdf  example, and real life examples after. But to understand the mechanics, a foobar type example is best.  Even with inheritance.. class A has a field,  class B extends A. You need to instinctively know what will happen. It's no good if you only know when it's animal and dog. Know for both then you know best. Know foobar well enough that you'll see animal/dog is gr8.

Answer (score 0):

When it is directly soliciting sales of some product or other.

Comment: I suppose a more correct way to phrase my question would have been "At what point does an answer become marketing?". A better still question would have been "Is an answer that is purely a link to a library and a large image with no technical value acceptable?". But thankfully the other contributors got what I meant in the general sense and were able to answer in the context of Stack Overflow.

Comment: My answer should have taken into account ambiguities in phraseology.