# Self-promotion in images

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69616670/calculate-uiview-x-and-y-from-angle) which contains an image of a diagram — drawn on paper — with "alhua technology" prominently displayed. It kind of looked like a watermark. I'm not sure if OP works for the company, and it's probably more likely that it was just a piece of scratch paper, but would self-promotion in images be allowed? For example, putting a watermark on the corner of every image that you post?

Since it's now deleted, here is a screenshot for users <10k:

[image: 1]

Comment: That doesn't look like self promotion and just that the person used a piece of scrap paper they had to demonstrate what they wanted. The *real* problem with that question is the lack of effort, research, attempt and details of the problem they are having solving said issue.

Comment: It'd depend on the situation. I wouldn't consider the example self promotion, it may simply be the most convenient scratch paper they have available. but someone going out of their way to put a logo on every image? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ *Maybe we can cross that bridge when it happens.*

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317476

Comment: Self promotion without affiliation disclosure is spam, and should be flagged as such, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). I’m pretty sure this is a dupe, but I can’t find one.

Comment: @EkadhSingh, but __is__ this self-promotion? No... It's not.

Comment: @Cerbrus I didn’t say it was self promotion, I said self promotion should be flagged as spam (I can’t view images right now, so I have no idea what it says)

Comment: Oh, your comment reads as if you were saying it's self-promotion, spam, and thus should be flagged.

Comment: Was this really the biggest problem you could find with this question? If someone wanted to promote a brand, they wouldn't do it by asking very poor questions on SO. If anything it's a defaming campaign.

Comment: The image could probably be cropped further to contain less of the logo.

Comment: I can't find the reference but I think I remember a discussion about copyright notices in code snippets on SO and the result was that one could not simply remove them. This here and copyright notices are somewhat similar. Maybe the logo actually would have to stay and one could not simply cut them out, even if one wanted to. Not sure though, because I'm also not sure about the legal status of the included images ([see these comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370334/what-is-the-future-for-imgur-and-se)).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

*In this specific case*, it's probably just a piece of whatever OP had laying around.

In a general sense, if a user makes a habit out adding watermarked images to their contributions, I think that could potentially be described as spam. But then again, that completely depends on severity, and needs to be judged on a case-by-case basis.

I've never seen users deliberately watermark their images for use on SO, though, so this is a big *"what if"*...

Comment: *"it's probably just a piece of whatever OP had laying around."* - Especially considering OP is in India and is an iOS developer, while [Dahua Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dahua_Technology) are in Zhejiang, China and work in video surveillance.

Comment: Oooh, that's a _"D"_... I had no idea a _"D"_ could look like that...

Comment: Fun fact, I googled "Alhua Technology" and "Dahua Technology" came up in the results :p

Comment: No that's a j...

Comment: @TGrif No, it's a d, the circle of the d is around the a

Comment: Ooooh you're right

Comment: @Nick The HQ seems to be in China, but there is also a branch in India. So it is still possible that OP works there, but I agree with Cerbrus, not really important in this case.

Comment: Follow-up question: Is it still self-promotion if most users cannot decipher the company name? ;)

Comment: Wow, that really is a weird logo :3

Comment: why would it be spam if I'd watermark a drawing that would without the watermark be useful? It's just making attribution (that is required anyway) easier for anyone who copies the image and reuses it somewhere else and imho has nothing to do with spam

Comment: @lucidbrot: You're not required to watermark images in your posts. If a user is inserting some random brand in all his images, then he's spamming that brand name. That brand name has nothing to do with answering on SO.

Comment: I'm not required when posting the image, but if I draw an image and post it on SO, any future visitor is required to attribute it to me when they use the picture elsewhere. because it is shared under CC-BY-SA. If a brand made the drawing, and made it available for use, I would find it problematic to *remove* the watermark, not to leave it in.

Comment: @lucidbrot: We're not talking about incidental brands in some images here... We're talking about users that consistently add watermarks to embedded images that are not relevant to the question. That _could __potentially__ be described as spam_.

Comment: @Cerbrus Alright, I can leave it at this. I read the "potentially" as "likely" and I wanted to point out that I think if a user wants to add their username to each of their contributions, that is valid. But I agree that this should be considered on a case-by-case basis and if that's what "potentially" means then we aren't even disagreeing as much as I thought

Comment: Yea, the premise of this Meta question is quite hypothetical already :-)

Comment: @honk kind of a follow-up: I had to ask: [what exactly makes this logo a design failure?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/154328/what-exactly-makes-this-logo-a-design-failure)